# Import OsmBonusPack for OsmDroid

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am using OsmDroid in my project. I imported the project using:

```
compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.5'
```

Now I want to use osmbonuspack, but I cant find compile name for this library. How to import osmbonuspack? using Jar?

Answer (score 3):

In the build.gradle of your Project (top level), add the jitpack repository:

```
repositories { 
     ...
     maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

Then in the build.gradle of your app, add this dependency:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.MKergall:osmbonuspack:6.4'
}
```

I found the guide [here](https://github.com/MKergall/osmbonuspack/wiki/HowToInclude)